# Typescript pass type to generic interface

Tags: typescript

I have this response type

```
export interface IResponse {
  status: boolean;
  message: string;
}
```

Then I would like to pass a custom interface to this type.

```
const res: IResponse<{count: number}> = await ...
```

How to modify my type so that `res.count` is recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a new generic type as an alias of an intersection type:

```
type CustomResponse<T> = IResponse & T

export function test() {
  const res: CustomResponse<{count: number}> = { }
  
  console.log(res.status) // true
  console.log(res.count)  // 1
}
```

Note that [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) will "lock" the type, as then `CustomResponse` is not an interface anymore and therefore can't be extended.

```
// Compile error
export interface A extends CustomType<string> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be:

```
const res: IResponse<IResponse & {count: number}> = await ...
```

the second one @Hoff stated. You need to extend IResponse with your custom one

Although I think it would be better for you do do something like:

```
export interface IResponse {
  status: boolean;
  message: string;
}

export type TResponse<T> = IResponse & T;

export interface Count {
  count: number
}

const res: IResponse<Count> = await ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do exactly, but if you want to extend an interface you can do it like so:

```
interface ExtendedResponse extends IResponse {
    count: number
}
```

Then you can use it as you would any other interface:

```
const res: ExtendedResponse = await ...
```

Comment: I can do that but passing the type on the fly is more flexible. I don't want to have to create an interface for each post request.